# Contact form doesn't send email

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

When I used only text, it worked. But when I added checkbox and radio buttons, it doesn't send. Whats wrong?
Sorry for russian text, buyer is from Russia.

```js
<?php
/* Наш Email */
$myemail  = "you@domain.com";
$subject  = "Контактная форма " $yourname;

/* Проверка полей */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname']);
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$telefon  = check_input($_POST['telefon']);
$proizvedeniye = check_input($_POST['proizvedeniye']);
$listi    = check_input($_POST['listi']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments']);
$oblojka  = check_input($_POST['oblojka']);
$maket    = check_input($_POST['maket']);
$uslugi   = check_input($_POST['uslugi']);
$interesuyet   = check_input($_POST['interesuyet']);

/* Если email не корректен */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail адрес не корректен");
}

/* Издание по пакету */
if($interesuyet = paket)
{
    $vibor_paketa= check_input($_POST['vibor_paketa'])
    $interesuyet = $vibor_paketa
}

/* Приходящий email */
$message = "Привет!

Получено письмо с контактной формы сайта "Написанно пером":

Имя: $yourname
E-mail: $email
Телефон: $telefon
Название произведения: $proizvedeniye 
Объем произведения в авторских листах: $listi 

Имеется ли обложка? - $oblojka
Имеется ли макет книги? - $maket
Если необходимы услуги, то какие? - $uslugi
Что интересует: $interesuyet

Комментарии: $comments
";

/* Отправить email по mail функции */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/*PopUp для благодарностей */
header('javascript:PopUpShow()');
exit();

/* Функцию использовали */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Пожалуйста исправьте ошибку:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    padding: 20px 15%;
  }
  form header {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
  }
  form header div {
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #999;
  }
  form header h2 {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  form > div {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
  form > div > fieldset > div > div {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  form > div > label,
  legend {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  form > div > div,
  form > div > fieldset > div {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
  }
  form > div > fieldset label {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  fieldset {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=url],
  input[type=password],
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=url],
  input[type=password] {
    width: 50%;
  }
  input[type=text]:focus,
  input[type=email]:focus,
  input[type=url]:focus,
  input[type=password]:focus,
  textarea:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #4697e4;
  }

  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    form > div {
      margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
    }
    form > div > label,
    legend {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
      margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    }
    form > div > div,
    form > div > fieldset > div {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
    }
    input[type=text],
    input[type=email],
    input[type=url],
    input[type=password],
    textarea,
    select {
      width: 100%; 
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    form > div > label,
    legend {
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
```

```html
<form action="#">

  <header>
    <h2>Контактная форма</h2>
  </header>
  
  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="yourname" for="yourname">Полное имя</label>
    <div>
      <input id="yourname_0" name="yourname" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1">
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="email" for="email">Email</label>
    <div>
      <input id="email_0" name="email" type="email" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3"> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="telefon" for="telefon">Контактный телефон</label>
    <div>
      <input id="telefon_0" name="telefon" type="tel" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3"> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="proizvedeniye" for="proizvedeniye">Название произведения</label>
    <div>
      <input id="proizvedeniye_0" name="proizvedeniye" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="listi" for="listi">Объем произведения в авторских листах</label>
    <div>
      <input id="listi_0" name="listi" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1">
    </div>
  </div>

    
  <div>
    <fieldset>    
      <legend id="oblojka" class="desc">У меня имеется обложка:</legend>
      <div>
        <input id="oblojkaradio" name="oblojka" type="hidden" value="">
        <div>
          <input id="oblojka_1" name="oblojka" type="radio" value="da" tabindex="5" checked="checked">
          <label class="choice" for="oblojka_1">Да</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="oblojka_0" name="oblojka" type="radio" value="net" tabindex="6">
          <label class="choice" for="oblojka_0">Нет, хочу заказать дизайн у вас</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  
    
  <div>
    <fieldset>    
      <legend id="maket" class="desc">У меня имеется макет книги:</legend>
      <div>
        <input id="maketradio" name="maket" type="hidden" value="">
        <div>
          <input id="maket_1" name="maket" type="radio" value="dae" tabindex="5" checked="checked">
          <label class="choice" for="maket_1">Да</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="maket_0" name="maket" type="radio" value="net" tabindex="6">
          <label class="choice" for="maket_0">Нет, хочу заказать макет у вас</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div>
    <fieldset>    
      <legend id="uslugi" class="desc">Мне не обходимы следующий услуги:</legend>
      <div>
        <input id="uslugiradio" name="uslugi" type="hidden" value="">
        <div>
          <input id="uslugi_1" name="uslugi" type="radio" value="redaktura" tabindex="5" checked="checked">
          <label class="choice" for="uslugi_1">Редактура</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="uslugi_2" name="uslugi" type="radio" value="korrektura" tabindex="6">
          <label class="choice" for="uslugi_2">Корректура</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="uslugi_0" name="uslugi" type="radio" value="net" tabindex="7">
          <label class="choice" for="uslugi_0">Спасибо, мой текст в порядке</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>


  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend id="interesuyet" class="desc">
        Меня интересует:
      </legend>
      <div>
      <div>
        <input id="interesuyet_1" name="interesuyet[]" type="checkbox" value="vibor_paketa" tabindex="8">
        <label class="choice" for="interesuyet_1">
          Издание по пакету:
          <div>
            <select id="vibor_paketa_cb" name="paket" class="field select medium" tabindex="11"> 
              <option value="paket_1">Пакет 1</option>
              <option value="paket_2">Пакет 2</option>
              <option value="paket_3">Пакет 3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="interesuyet_2" name="interesuyet[]" type="checkbox" value="electron_only" tabindex="9">
        <label class="choice" for="interesuyet_2">Издание и распространение исключительно электронной книги</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="interesuyet_3" name="interesuyet[]" type="checkbox" value="paper_only" tabindex="10">
        <label class="choice" for="interesuyet_3">Издание и распространение только в бумажном виде</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="interesuyet_4" name="interesuyet[]" type="checkbox" value="print" tabindex="10">
        <label class="choice" for="interesuyet_4">Печать</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="interesuyet_5" name="interesuyet[]" type="checkbox" value="spread_electron_audio" tabindex="10">
        <label class="choice" for="interesuyet_5">Распространение готовой электронной или аудиокниги</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="interesuyet_6" name="interesuyet[]" type="checkbox" value="make_audio" tabindex="10">
        <label class="choice" for="interesuyet_6">Изготовление аудиокниги</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="interesuyet_7" name="interesuyet[]" type="checkbox" value="optimize_audio" tabindex="10">
        <label class="choice" for="interesuyet_7">Продвижение аудиокниги</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="comments" for="comments">Комментарии</label>
    <div>
      <textarea id="comments_0" name="comments" spellcheck="true" rows="10" cols="50" tabindex="4"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div>
      <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

I know that, I did something wrong on my php code, can you show me or help me.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

Comment: `header('javascript:PopUpShow()');` whut?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to show javascript popup

Comment: `$subject  = "Контактная форма " $yourname;` < --- this is a syntax error, too.  Maybe you meant: `$subject  = "Контактная форма " . $yourname;`